# Exclude packages from updates per repo

Tags: rhel, dnf

I have built some Asterisk 16 RPMs I serve to my network internally. In the last couple of weeks EPEL has started distributing an Asterisk RPM, but it's version 18. This creates a conflict when I try to run `dnf upgrade` on my servers.

I know I can exclude `asterisk*` from updates, either at the command line or in a config file, but this will prevent me from getting my internal updates.

Can I tell `dnf` to ignore the `asterisk*` packages in the EPEL repo but continue to update them from my internal repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You can add `exclude=asterisk*` in your epel repo conf.

Example (RHEL 7):

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-7&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
failovermethod=priority
repo_gpgcheck=0
metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-7&arch=$basearch
exclude=asterisk*
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks.